# How to centered bootstrap col-md-4 and col-md-5 in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two bootstrap items one col-md-5 and one col-md-4. But i want to centered these two items in the middle of the page, both of them. Now my col-md-4 is at the left side of the page and the col-md-5 is at the middle of the page. Has anyone an idea how to centered these two items without use only margin.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="klantcases">
    <h2>Company</h2>
    <li><a href="#">Over ons</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kernwaarden</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Missie en visie</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Nieuws</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Development Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Marketing Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Development</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Marketing</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Werken bij ons></li>
</div>
```

```
<div class="col-md-5">
<div class="blogpreview">
    <img src="img/kan.png" alt="kan" /><h1>The latest from our</br>
        DEVELOPMENT BLOG</h1>

    <img src="img/bloglaptop.jpg" alt="bloglaptopcode" />

    <div class="bloginfo"><h2>Woensdag 15 april 2015 - 12:05</h2></br></br>
        <h1>CSS styleable, vector based icons on every device (even IE8)</h1>
        <p>Icons have always been an important part of an interface. They allow the user to recognize certain actions with only a glance. In this blog, we will look for a complete and closing solution to render css-styleable icons that are supported by older browsers while still looking great on modern retina displays.</p>

        <a href="#"><h3 class="leesmeer">LEES MEER</h3></a>

        </div>


    <div class="meer">
        <h2>Maandag 13 april 2015 - 13:19</h2>
        <h1>Inline video on the iPhone</h2>
            <p>video has come a long way. We went from nitrate film, tape and VHS to digital video. From black and white tubes to full color 4k flatscreen televisions. And from static desktop environments to video more and more being something that you take with you by watching it on your mobile device. </p>
            <a href="#"><h3 class="leesmeer">LEES MEER</h3></a>
    </div>

        <div class="meer">
        <h2>Maandag 30 maart 2015 - 18:30</h2>
        <h1>Video in email: today or tomorrow?</h2>
            <p>You can and should be using video in email today! Video in email often is "the" missing link in business to consumer email communication. We did a lot of technical research and development and want to share some of the results with you today. </p>
            <a href="#"><h3 class="leesmeer">LEES MEER</h3></a>
    </div>



<img src="img/pfoon.png" alt="pfoon" /> <h1>The latest from our</br>
        MARKETING BLOG</h1>

    <img src="img/iphone.jpg" alt="iphonehand" />

    <div class="bloginfo2"><h2>Woensdag 15 april 2015 - 12:05</h2></br></br>
        <h1>CSS styleable, vector based icons on every device (even IE8)</h1>
        <p>Icons have always been an important part of an interface. They allow the user to recognize certain actions with only a glance. In this blog, we will look for a complete and closing solution to render css-styleable icons that are supported by older browsers while still looking great on modern retina displays.</p>

        <a href="#"><h3 class="leesmeer">LEES MEER</h3></a>

        </div>

        <div class="meer">
        <h2>Maandag 13 april 2015 - 13:19</h2>
        <h1>Inline video on the iPhone</h2>
            <p>video has come a long way. We went from nitrate film, tape and VHS to digital video. From black and white tubes to full color 4k flatscreen televisions. And from static desktop environments to video more and more being something that you take with you by watching it on your mobile device. </p>
            <a href="#"><h3 class="leesmeer">LEES MEER</h3></a>
    </div>

        <div class="meer">
        <h2>Maandag 30 maart 2015 - 18:30</h2>
        <h1>Video in email: today or tomorrow?</h2>
            <p>You can and should be using video in email today! Video in email often is "the" missing link in business to consumer email communication. We did a lot of technical research and development and want to share some of the results with you today. </p>
            <a href="#"><h3 class="leesmeer">LEES MEER</h3></a>
    </div>





</div>
```

Comment: did u tried center-block?

Comment: are the two col-md in the same row?

Comment: How should i do centered block? On both of the bootstrap items?

Comment: @kyriakos there is no row

Comment: you can wrap both columns in a single div and then center that div by giving it the center-block class like G.L.P said

Comment: i have add a row. Where both of the col-md are in.

Answer (score 0):

You can offset columns in bootstrap. [See Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).
By using a class such as, `col-md-offset-4` you can push your columns across the page.

In your case you would need to adjust your columns to make up an even total, e.g. `col-md-4` and `col-md-6`, and then add `col-md-offset-1` to offset the first column by 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

Since the Bootstrap default grid has 12 columns, you cannot center the 9 columns grid with the default Bootstrap offsets. So all you need to do is create a custom 1.5 offset (which left margin would be equal to 1.5/12*100% = 12.5%) and apply it to the `.col-md-4` container:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-custom">...</div>
        <div class="col-md-5">...</div>
    </div>
    <!-- / .row -->
</div>
<!-- / .container -->


@media(min-width: 992px && max-width: 1199px) {
    .col-md-offset-custom {
        margin-left: 12.5%;
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq06L4hb/2/